# Creating header with home page(Landing screen) button

Tags: android, android-layout

One of the application in my mobile has a header like the one shown below in the snapshot. I like the design very much and would like to create one for my application. Clicking the home icon takes the user to landing page(Home page). I have only created buttons of squarish and rounder corners. But not sure, how to create one like the one given below. Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Photoshop is your friend

Answer (score 1):

Create the image in photoshop or whatever.

Then create an imageview and let it act like a button:

```
<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/camera_button"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:src="@drawable/button_camera" 
 android:onClick="onCameraButtonClick" />
```

onClick is introduced in Android 1.6

or a button and set the background:

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/camera_button"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@drawable/button_camera" 
 android:onClick="onCameraButtonClick" />
```

drawable/camera_button should be a state drawable so the user can see when it is being clicked/focused.

in your activity:

```
 public void onCameraButtonClick(View v){
     // Do Something
 }
```

It's all here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I believe you have misunderstood my question...or may be I framed it wrongly. I can create 2 buttons(with background) and set the onclicklistener. But my question here is...as you can see from the snapshot..the 2 buttons are overlapping. how do we achieve that? Please do suggest me if you have any idea. In the mean time I will also try to do some hack and get back to you all with my result(If at all I get one).

Comment: If i get time i'll code this, but thinking about it: Two buttons wrapped in a relative layout with negative margins or something

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the idea. Tried with negative margins today as suggested by you.. and able to overlap 2 simple buttons :). Will post the actual button with layout and snapshot once it is done.

Answer (score 1):

The way that I would do this is just create the buttons in photoshop/GIMP on the same canvas then save each as PNG, you can use the slice tool for this. Then I would just add an attributes to each button. There's attributes that let you set the left margin of say the right button to line up with the right margin of the left button. The backgrounds of the buttons could also be patch9 images, and the icons inside it could be the src attribute of the button view. The button with the camera would have SRC pointing to a PNG that has the camera icon as well as "Camera". And the button itself not having any text.